# Upgrading Firebase broke my iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I wish I had never updated my pod, the entire project was full of errors, one specific error is in the photo below, I can't fix it and I was ready to submit my app to the App Store now it seems like its all ruined. On top of this, it made me erase a bunch of optionals.

[image: error message]

```
 func uploadData(user: User) {
    let changeRequest = user.createProfileChangeRequest()
    changeRequest.displayName = self.nameUser.text!
    changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: nil)

    let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(user.uid).jpg")

    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!, 0.5)

    let uploadTask = imageRef.put(data!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
        }

        imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, er) in
            if er != nil {
                print(er!.localizedDescription)
            }


            if let url = url {



                let userInfo: [String : Any] =  ["age" : self.ageUser.text!,
                                                 "location" : self.location.text!,
                                                 "name" : self.nameUser.text!,
                                                 "image" : url.absoluteString,
                                                 "bio" : self.bioViewTwo.text!,
                                                 "contact" : self.contactUser.text!
                ]

                self.ref.child("SJ").child(user.uid).setValue(userInfo)

            }

        })

    })

    uploadTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you just upgraded to Firebase version 4 ;) This new version contains many breaking changes (and [some good stuff](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#4.0.0) too!) for *Swift*
 based projects.

You should [follow their migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide#detailed_list_of_changes) to fix your issues. For instance, the error you highlighted, on the `StorageReference` class, can easily be fixed by renaming the offending `put` method to `putData`, and so on.

By the way, no naming changes have been made to the *Objective-C* SDK.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was panicking for nothing, may I ask what exactly these "good stuff" are that you speak of?

Comment: Please see [this list](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#4.0.0) for a quick summary of the major changes. There also many nice videos on their YouTube channel as well.