# UI API called from background thread in Swift 4 and running Firebase 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift4

These are the errors that are currently present in my project after I downloaded the beta version of **Xcode 9**.

[image: Error messages]

This directly connects [to this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391367/swift-4-uiapplication-registerforremotenotifications-must-be-called-from-mai) In which similar problem is solved. I had this problem as well originally and fixed it by following the accepted solution. However, that did not fix these other error messages that I am getting.

What is causing these? Are they a problem? How can I prevent them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your stack trace, it looks like *both* calls are Firebase related. As such, try upgrading to the latest Firebase version 4.x to see if those go away.

[Please see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44092749/819340) if you may need some help when doing so.

**Update**. Actually, it looks like [this is a known issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/69) in Firebase v4 iOS SDK :-(

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that as well, however, I already have Firebase 4.

Comment: Ok, I think I confused Objectice-C vs Swift Firebase classes naming ;) Anyway, can you show us the code triggering such errors?

Comment: That is one of my problems I don't know what code is actually triggering these errors.

Comment: According to the GitHub *issue* I just linked, these calls may be coming from *within* the Firebase iOS SDK — and these may even be false positives, so you may be good for now ;)